# Hibernate Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to understand how to get a list from hibernate - yet I keep getting errors such as objects cannot be created directly on components. While I have searched for solutions to this and I have found references saying to create an alias - this seems to fail in my situation. Specifically, I am trying to query an object on one element of a composite key.

Given the following two classes:

```
@Embeddable
public class CveReferenceId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String refsource;
    private String refname;
    private String cveid;

    @Column(name = "refsource", nullable = false)
    public String getRefsource() {return this.refsource;}
    public void setRefsource(String refsource) {this.refsource = refsource;}

    @Column(name = "refname", nullable = false)
    public String getRefname() {return this.refname;}
    public void setRefname(String refname) {this.refname = refname;}

    @Column(name = "cveid", nullable = false)
    public String getCveid() {return this.cveid;}
    public void setCveid(String cveid) {this.cveid = cveid;}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cve_reference")
@Immutable
public class CveReference implements java.io.Serializable {

    private CveReferenceId id;

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refsource", column = @Column(name = "refsource", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "refname", column = @Column(name = "refname", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "cveid", column = @Column(name = "cveid", nullable = false))})
    public CveReferenceId getId() {return this.id;}
    public void setId(CveReferenceId id) {this.id = id;}
}
```

When I try to execute the following code to retrieve a list of CVE References I get 'not an association: id.cveid':

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CveReference.class)
    .createAlias("id.cveid", "refid")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("refid", "CVE-2013-1950"));
List<CveReference> refs = criteria.list();
```

When I run the following code I get 'Criteria objects cannot be created directly on components.  Create a criteria on owning entity and use a dotted property to access component property':

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CveReference.class)
    .createAlias("id", "ref")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("ref.id", "CVE-2013-1950"));
List<CveReference> refs = criteria.list();
```

Any hints as to what I am missing here would be greatly appreciated.

--Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem. Apparently, the generated annotations were not correct and I needed to use @IdClass. The following works:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cve_reference")
@IdClass(CveReferenceId.class)
@Immutable
public class CveReference implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String refsource;
    private String refname;
    private String cveid;

    public CveReference() {
    }

    public CveReference(String refsource, String refname, String cveid) {
        this.refsource = refsource;
        this.refname = refname;
        this.cveid = cveid;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "refsource", nullable = false)
    public String getRefsource() {
        return this.refsource;
    }

    public void setRefsource(String refsource) {
        this.refsource = refsource;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "refname", nullable = false)
    public String getRefname() {
        return this.refname;
    }

    public void setRefname(String refname) {
        this.refname = refname;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "cveid", nullable = false)
    public String getCveid() {
        return this.cveid;
    }

    public void setCveid(String cveid) {
        this.cveid = cveid;
    }
}


public class CveReferenceId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String refsource;
    private String refname;
    private String cveid;

    public CveReferenceId() {
    }

    public CveReferenceId(String refsource, String refname, String cveid) {
        this.refsource = refsource;
        this.refname = refname;
        this.cveid = cveid;
    }

    public String getRefsource() {
        return this.refsource;
    }

    public void setRefsource(String refsource) {
        this.refsource = refsource;
    }

    public String getRefname() {
        return this.refname;
    }

    public void setRefname(String refname) {
        this.refname = refname;
    }

    public String getCveid() {
        return this.cveid;
    }

    public void setCveid(String cveid) {
        this.cveid = cveid;
    }
}
```

Then creating the criteria as follows:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CveReference.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("cveid", "CVE-2013-1950"));
List<CveReference> refs = criteria.list();
```